# WSS 3.0 List - Change default view

Tags: development, wss-3.0

Is there a way to change the default view on a WSS 3.0 list (Survey)?

I tried

web.Lists[].DefaultViewURL = "\List\xxxyyy\custompage.aspx"

But DefaultviewURL looks like it is read-only.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to the view within the view collection.  There is a property that can identify that view as the default view which should then update the DefaultViewURL property of the list.